# EC2: Apache caught SIGTERM, shutting down

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache

I have been trying to get a basic apache web server running on EC2 but having difficulties doing so.

So far I have tried this on 5 different instances (3 public ones, 2 basic amazon ones). I have created 5 new ones just trying to get apache up. After every instance I have installed `httpd` by a simple `yum install` and then tried to start the service.

2 of the 3 public images were LAMP servers (already configured) and after I started them, I tried running the service and tailing the log file.

To my surprise, every single time on 5 completely different instances, I received the exact same errors in the `error_log` file and saw nothing in the browser.

Here is the error.

```
[Tue Feb 28 06:20:50 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Feb 28 06:20:50 2012] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Feb 28 06:20:50 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Feb 28 06:20:50 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Feb 28 06:20:52 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Does anyone have any idea on what this is and how to fix it? couldnt seem to find anything else on the web and the vague answers that existed, didnt work.

Thanks

Comment: Any solutions so far?